# R - How to preserve data types and titles when converting list of lists to data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, matrix, coercion

I'm working with a list `receipts` of lists. Each entry in `receipts` contains a list representing a receipt. The structure of a receipt is consistent and looks like this.

```
> str(receipts[[1]])
List of 6
 $ receipt_type  : chr "SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY"
 $ timestamp     : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2020-01-01 09:29:00"
 $ receipt_number: int 1195
 $ POS           : int 1
 $ KNo           : int 12
 $ shift_number  : int 9
```

The `receipt_number` may contain `NA` values as well.

I'd like to convert this list into a data frame with corresponding columns (`receipt_type`, `timestamp`, `receipt_number`, etc..). Currently I'm using this

```
receipts_as_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(receipts), byrow=TRUE, ncol=length(receipts[[1]])))
```

This puts the data into a data frame. Sadly the `unlist` removes all information about the types of the data (I think everything is coerced to `character`). Furthermore the column names get lost as well. Thus, I have a data frame with all the data, but the types and column-names are lost.

I know that I could rename the columns and datatypes manually, but was wondering whether there is a more comfortable way of handling this situation.

**Example:** Currently the data frame looks like this

```
> head(receipts_as_df)
                        V1         V2   V3 V4 V5 V6
1     SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY 1577867340 1195  1 12  9
2 CASH_REGISTER_MONITORING 1577867340 <NA>  1 12  9
3      PAYOUT_NOTIFICATION 1577867340 1196  1 12  9
4             TSE_ACTIVITY 1577869080 <NA>  1 12  9
5   BUSINESS_MODE_ACTIVITY 1577869080 <NA>  1 12  9
6             ZERO_RECEIPT 1577869140 1197  1 12  9
```

Comment: `do.call(rbind.data.frame, receipts)`? Also `dplyr::bind_rows(receipts)` or `data.table::rbindlist(receipts)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R, a little more work needed:

```r
receipts <- replicate(3, list(
  receipt_type   = "SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY",
  timestamp      = as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 09:29:00", tz = "UTC"),
  receipt_number = 1195,
  POS            = 1,
  KNo            = 12,
  shift_number   = 9
), simplify = FALSE)

out <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, c(receipts, list(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
out
#            receipt_type  timestamp receipt_number POS KNo shift_number
# 2  SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY 1577870940           1195   1  12            9
# 21 SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY 1577870940           1195   1  12            9
# 3  SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY 1577870940           1195   1  12            9
str(out)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ receipt_type  : chr  "SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY" "SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY" "SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY"
#  $ timestamp     : num  1.58e+09 1.58e+09 1.58e+09
#  $ receipt_number: num  1195 1195 1195
#  $ POS           : num  1 1 1
#  $ KNo           : num  12 12 12
#  $ shift_number  : num  9 9 9
out$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(out$timestamp, origin = "1970-01-01")
out
#            receipt_type           timestamp receipt_number POS KNo shift_number
# 2  SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY 2020-01-01 01:29:00           1195   1  12            9
# 21 SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY 2020-01-01 01:29:00           1195   1  12            9
# 3  SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY 2020-01-01 01:29:00           1195   1  12            9
```

`dplyr` and `data.table` without extra work needed:

```r
dplyr::bind_rows(receipts)
# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#   receipt_type         timestamp           receipt_number   POS   KNo shift_number
#   <chr>                <dttm>                       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY 2020-01-01 09:29:00           1195     1    12            9
# 2 SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY 2020-01-01 09:29:00           1195     1    12            9
# 3 SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY 2020-01-01 09:29:00           1195     1    12            9
data.table::rbindlist(receipts)
#            receipt_type           timestamp receipt_number POS KNo shift_number
# 1: SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY 2020-01-01 09:29:00           1195   1  12            9
# 2: SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY 2020-01-01 09:29:00           1195   1  12            9
# 3: SALESPERSON_ACTIVITY 2020-01-01 09:29:00           1195   1  12            9
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd like to work with base R but I'm worried about the index `21` in `do.call(rbind.data.frame, c(receipts, list(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))`. What is happening here?

Comment: It's a row name, so generally easily ignorable; it's an artifact of the `rbind` process, which makes no effort to set or fix row names that are inferred. If you are concerned, then you can "reset" the row names with `rownames(out) <- NULL` (to reset them to strings of integers).

Comment: This works. Thank you. I know that it won't make a difference, but it is nicer to look at...